# create trigger sys_exec but sql file run in phpmyadmin data insert time error?

Tags: php, mysql, database-trigger

Create trigger  in phpmyadmin than insert time php file throw send push notificatio in php. got this some error , how to solution 
I want to call an external program (php script) via MySQL's sys_* UDFs. Now, the issue - the trigger I have passes the ID of the record to the script. When I try to pull the data out via the script
Error
SQL query:

CREATE FUNCTION lib_mysqludf_sys_info RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
MySQL said: Documentation
 #1044 - Access denied for user 'Eric_iloho'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

file name [this link](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys) run code  sql file name 'lib_mysqludf_sys.sql' . how to solution in file .
I am trying to call push .php name by using mysql trigger.This is the code of mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `push_Trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_push_notifications`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);    
DECLARE result int(10);    
SET cmd=CONCAT('http://107.180.100.93/api/push.php');   
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END
```

i insert new entry time got error -
Error
SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_push_notifications` (`id`, `message_id`, `from_user_id`, 
    `to_user_id`, `message`, `is_sent`, `created_at`) VALUES
(11, 57, 'iloho_user_87@107.180.100.93/ilohoUser',     
'iloho_user_88@107.180.100.93', 'Offline message', 0, '2016-07-03 03:23:04');
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1305 - FUNCTION Eric_iloho_db.sys_exec does not exist .

please help me
thanks